# How do I upload Image to /{group-id}/photos with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to post to a facebook group using the code below, but I get "(#120) Invalid album id" as the response. However, the caption will be posted to the group without the photo.

```
$data=array('url'=>$photo_src,  'caption' => $caption);
$response = $fb->post($group_id . '/photos', $data);
```

I have no idea where album id is coming from since it is not a field in the photos edge (/{group-id}/photos).

I tried hard coding the image src to a remote image (I double checked to see that it actually exists), and also tried using the `fileToUpload()` method and none worked

Additional Information

When I use

```
$data=array('message'=>$message);
$response = $fb->post($group_id . '/feed', $data);
```

It gets posted correctly. Which means that the Facebook super class configuration (appId, app secret) is correct. Also, accesstoken is set using `setDefaultAccessToken()`.

**Update**
To clear @luschn questions, I created a group album and tried the /{album-id}/photos edge, but it did not work. The response I got is

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The specified photoset id is invalid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AFest626CTTkyF1ABb_keIV"
  }
}
```

How can I solve the image upload issue?

Comment: i believe there is a default album you need to use, unless you do not want to post to a specific one.

Comment: I forgot to add, I created an album and tried the /{album-id}/photos edge, but it did not work. The response I got is  

```{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The specified photoset id is invalid",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "AFest626CTTkyF1ABb_keIV"
  }
}```

Comment: If I may ask, is there a way to specify an album id on /{group-id}/photos?. On the documentation 'aid' has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty workaround.

I am putting this here pending the time a better solution will be given.

I posted the photo as a link.

```
$data=array('link'=>$photo_src,'message'=>$caption);
$response = $fb->post($group_id . '/feed', $data);
```

Facebook will generate a preview of the image from the link